# How would one find what index in a set of multiples a certain number would exist in?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

Apologies if my terminology is way off, or my chosen tag makes no sense.

Consider the following set of numbers; where each number is a multiple of 4 (except for 1)

{1, 4, 16, 64, 256}

Let min = 1, and let max = the sum of the set (in this case: 341).

Let x = min <= x <= max

Let i = an index within the set (in this case: 0 - 4)

How would I go about finding what index within the set x fits in? For example:

if x = 18; i should be 1, because (1 + 4) < 18 < (1 + 4 + 16)

Is there a way to solve this without iteration? My first instinct is to brute force it by continually summing portions of the set until I reach a number larger than x, but I am interested in an approach that does not use iteration (if possible).

Comment: Pre-compute the list of the partial sums ($1, 5, 21, 85, 341$), and do a binary search in that?

Comment: log may help but it is often computed as a sum. If it is just for this set or another small set, the simplest way is to compare the entry to {1,5,21,85,341}

Comment: Alternatively, since your numbers are just $4^n$, the partial sums are $\frac{4^i-1}{3}$, so if you can compute logarithms in constant time, then $\log_4(3x+1)$ should give you the index with no overt iteration.

Comment: @HenningMakholm your log approach works perfectly. I just have to floor the result to get a proper index of course, but it works! I don't fully understand how though. Where does the number 3 come in?

Comment: @user984444: From the general formula for a finite geometric series: $$ 1 + a + a^2 + \cdots +a^n = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$ Here $a=4$, so the numerator is $3$.

Comment: for large sets, you must see the Fabian answer on [Find the highest order bit in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161/find-the-highest-order-bit-in-c) . Indeed , the highest order bit of the entry may be a shortcut of log